# Push notifications with ionic.io doesn't arrive

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic.io

Recently I changed my account email address, and notifications stop working. I was on alpha version, so I migrated to beta, thinking that was the problem. Currently I'm on beta version, but still didn´t receive niotifications. I have configured dev_push to false, and I created the security profile with the apn certtificate and the gcm key. The devices are correctly registered as console log and dashboard ifnormation, but if a send a test push from dasboard never arrives to iOS or Andorid. Can you help me?

I got it working on Android, but not on iOS. I'm getting always APNS_BAD_DEVICE_TOKEN, I check my security profile and is OK

Comment: Have you updated your sender Id for the Android app?

Comment: @Mathews yes, and is not working on iOS also

Comment: For iOS which service are you using APNS or GCM?

Comment: @Mathews APNS for iOS and GCM for Android

Comment: Changing email account shouldn't affect iOS. For iOS what kind of build are you testing? Direct build from Xcode, TestFlight or ipa?

Comment: Xcode and Testflight.  ANd android si not working also

Comment: I got it working on Android, but not on iOS. I'm getting always APNS_BAD_DEVICE_TOKEN, I check my security profile and is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make all steps from scratch and test with TestFlight build. I can't get ir work with XCode build, not on debug and not on release.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing directly to your phone from Xcode, then you have to use Development security profile and make sure you are sending the notification from server side to iOS devlopment sand box. 
If you are using TestFlight you need to use Production profile and make sure you are sending the notification to iOS production sandbox.